# Converting predicate logic formulas into Skolem Normal Form

Tags: predicate-logic, quantifiers, conjunctive-normal-form

I would like to transform the following predicate logic formulas into **Skolem Normal Form**, **simplifying** them as much as possible. 
I am trying to show my working clearly, writing each step in a line of its own and indicating how it was obtained. However I am not sure if I am doing correctly (simplifying in right places, removing enough brackets etc.) and efficiently.

I am trying to use the following **skolemization algorithm**:

1. Replace all occurrences of →, ↔, ⊕.
2. Move negation inwards.
3. Standardize variables apart.
4. Rewrite existential quantifiers using
   Skolem Functions.
5. Move universal quantifiers to front.
6. Use the Distributivity Law.

**a)** $∃x (dog(x) ∧ ∀y (dog(y) → admires(y, x)))$

$$∃x \space (dog(x) ∧ \neg∀y \space (dog(y)\wedge  admires(y, x))) \qquad  \text{(def. →)}$$
$$∃x \space (dog(x) ∧ ∃y\space \neg(dog(y)\wedge  admires(y, x))) \qquad  \text{(De Morgan)}$$
$$∃x \space (dog(x) ∧ ∃y\space (\neg dog(y)\vee \neg admires(y, x))) \qquad  \text{(De Morgan)}$$
$$∃x_1 \space (dog(x_1) ∧ ∃y_1\space (\neg dog(y_1)\vee \neg admires(y_1, x_1))) \qquad  \text{(Standardize)}$$
$$((dog(dog\_x) ∧ (\neg dog(dog\_y)\vee \neg admires(dog\_y, dog\_x))) \qquad  \text{(Skolemize)}$$
$$((dog(dog\_x) ∧ (\neg dog(dog\_y))) \vee (dog(dog\_x) ∧ \neg admires(dog\_y, dog\_x))) \qquad  \text{(Distributivity)}$$
... some conversion from Disjunctive to Conjunctive normal form? (unsure how)

**b)** $∀x (∀y (dog(y) → admires(y, x)) ↔ ∀y (dog(y) → stronger(x, y)))$

$$∀x (∀y (\neg dog(y) \vee admires(y, x)) ↔ ∀y (\neg dog(y) \vee stronger(x, y))) \qquad  \text{(def. →)}$$
$$∀x (∀y (\neg dog(y) \vee admires(y, x)) → ∀y (\neg dog(y) \vee stronger(x, y)) )\space ∧ \space (∀y (\neg dog(y) \vee stronger(x, y)) → ∀y (\neg dog(y) \vee admires(y, x))) \qquad  \text{(def. ↔)}$$
$$∀x (\neg ∀y (\neg dog(y) \vee admires(y, x)) \vee ∀y (\neg dog(y) \vee stronger(x, y)) )\space ∧ \space (\neg ∀y (\neg dog(y) \vee stronger(x, y)) \vee (∀y (\neg dog(y) \vee admires(y, x))) \qquad  \text{(def. →)}$$
$$∀x (∃x \neg(\neg dog(y) \vee admires(y, x)) \vee ∀y (\neg dog(y) \vee stronger(x, y)) )\space ∧ \space (∃x \neg(\neg dog(y) \vee stronger(x, y)) \vee (∀y (\neg dog(y) \vee admires(y, x))) \qquad  \text{(De Morgan)}$$
$$∀x (∃x (\neg\neg dog(y) ∧ \neg admires(y, x)) \vee ∀y (\neg dog(y) \vee stronger(x, y)) )\space ∧ \space (∃x (\neg\neg dog(y) ∧ \neg stronger(x, y)) \vee (∀y (\neg dog(y) \vee admires(y, x))) \qquad  \text{(De Morgan)}$$
$$∀x (∃x (dog(y) ∧ \neg admires(y, x)) \vee ∀y (\neg dog(y) \vee stronger(x, y)) )\space ∧ \space (∃x (dog(y) ∧ \neg stronger(x, y)) \vee (∀y (\neg dog(y) \vee admires(y, x))) \qquad  \text{(Double Negation)}$$
$$∀x (∃x_1 (dog(y) ∧ \neg admires(y, x_1)) \vee ∀y (\neg dog(y) \vee stronger(x_1, y)) )\space ∧ \space (∃x_2 (dog(y) ∧ \neg stronger(x_2, y)) \vee (∀y (\neg dog(y) \vee admires(y, x_2))) \qquad  \text{(Standardize)}$$
$$∀x ((dog(y) ∧ \neg admires(y, dog\_x)) \vee ∀y (\neg dog(y) \vee stronger(dog\_x, y)) )\space ∧ \space ((dog(y) ∧ \neg stronger(dog\_z, y)) \vee (∀y (\neg dog(y) \vee admires(y, dog\_z))) \qquad  \text{(Skolemize)}$$
... some distributive step to bring universal quantifiers to front and make matrix conjunctive normal form? (unsure how)

---

Second attempt after reviewing answers:
**a)**

$$∃x \space (dog(x) ∧ ∀y (dog(y) → admires(y, x)))$$

$$∃x \space (dog(x) ∧ ∀y \space (\neg dog(y) ∨ admires(y, x))) \qquad  \text{(def. →)}$$

$$∃x ∀y \space (dog(x) ∧ \space (\neg dog(y) ∨ admires(y, x))) \qquad  \text{(by Prenex Law)}$$

$$∃x_1 ∀y \space (dog(x_1) ∧ \space (\neg dog(y) ∨ admires(y, x_1))) \qquad  \text{(Standardize)}$$

$$∀y \space (dog(dog_x) ∧ \space (\neg dog(y) ∨ admires(y, dog_x))) \qquad  \text{(Skolemize) Done!}$$

**b)**

$$∀x (∀y (dog(y) → admires(y, x)) ↔ ∀y (dog(y) → stronger(x, y)))$$

$$∀x (∀y (\neg dog(y) ∨ admires(y, x)) ↔ ∀y (\neg dog(y) ∨ stronger(x, y))) \qquad  \text{(def. →)}$$

$$∀x ((∀y (\neg dog(y) \vee admires(y, x)) → ∀y (\neg dog(y) \vee stronger(x, y)) )\space ∧ \space (∀y (\neg dog(y) \vee stronger(x, y)) → ∀y (\neg dog(y) \vee admires(y, x)))) \qquad  \text{(def. ↔)}$$

$$∀x ((\neg ∀y (\neg dog(y) \vee admires(y, x)) \vee ∀y (\neg dog(y) \vee stronger(x, y)) )\space ∧ \space (\neg ∀y (\neg dog(y) \vee stronger(x, y)) \vee ∀y (\neg dog(y) \vee admires(y, x)))) \qquad  \text{(def. →)}$$

$$∀x ((∃y \neg(\neg dog(y) \vee admires(y, x)) \vee ∀y (\neg dog(y) \vee stronger(x, y)) )\space ∧ \space (∃y \neg(\neg dog(y) \vee stronger(x, y)) \vee ∀y (\neg dog(y) \vee admires(y, x)))) \qquad  \text{(De Morgan)}$$

$$∀x ((∃y (\neg\neg dog(y) ∧ \neg admires(y, x)) \vee ∀y (\neg dog(y) \vee stronger(x, y)) )\space ∧ \space (∃y (\neg\neg dog(y) ∧ \neg stronger(x, y)) \vee ∀y (\neg dog(y) \vee admires(y, x)))) \qquad  \text{(De Morgan)}$$

$$∀x ((∃y (dog(y) ∧ \neg admires(y, x)) \vee ∀y (\neg dog(y) \vee stronger(x, y)) )\space ∧ \space (∃y (dog(y) ∧ \neg stronger(x, y)) \vee ∀y (\neg dog(y) \vee admires(y, x)))) \qquad  \text{(Double Negation)}$$

$$∀x ∀y (∃y(dog(y) ∧ \neg admires(y, x)) \vee (\neg dog(y) \vee stronger(x, y)) )\space ∧ \space (∃y (dog(y) ∧ \neg stronger(x, y)) \vee (\neg dog(y) \vee admires(y, x)) \qquad  \text{(Scope Change)}$$

$$∀x ∀y (∃y_1(dog(y_1) ∧ \neg admires(y_1, x)) \vee (\neg dog(y) \vee stronger(x, y)) )\space ∧ \space (∃y_2 (dog(y_2) ∧ \neg stronger(x, y_2)) \vee (\neg dog(y) \vee admires(y, x)) \qquad  \text{(Standardize)}$$

$$∀x ∀y ((dog(dog\_y1) ∧ \neg admires(dog\_y1, x)) \vee (\neg dog(y) \vee stronger(x, y)) )\space ∧ \space ((dog(dog\_y2) ∧ \neg stronger(x, dog\_y2)) \vee (\neg dog(y) \vee admires(y, x)) \qquad  \text{(Skolemize)}$$

(distribute ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a)

you make a mistake in the very first step:

$\exists x (dog(x) \land \forall y (dog(y) \rightarrow admires(y,x))) \Leftrightarrow $ (by def. $\rightarrow$)

$\exists x (dog(x) \land \forall y (\neg dog(y) \lor admires(y,x)))$

I note that  in your algorithm you skolemize the existentials before bringing out (to the front) the quantifiers .. But in the process of binging them out the quantifiers may change (see Prenex 7 and 8 belo). So: *first* bring out the quantifier and then skolemize. Tip: try and get the existentials out first.

Also, when at the end you have something of the form $P \land (Q \lor R)$ it is already in  CNF ... So do *not* distribute at that point.

Finally, here are some basic rules for pulling a quantifier outside logical operators, where P does not contain any free variables x:

Prenex 1: $P \lor \forall x \: \phi(x) \Leftrightarrow  \forall x (P \lor  \phi(x))$

Prenex 2: $P \lor \exists x \: \phi(x) \Leftrightarrow  \exists x (P \lor  \phi(x))$

Prenex 3: $P \land \forall x \: \phi(x) \Leftrightarrow  \forall x (P \land  \phi(x))$

Prenex 4: $P \land \exists x \: \phi(x) \Leftrightarrow  \exists x (P \land  \phi(x))$

Prenex 5: $P \rightarrow \forall x \: \phi(x) \Leftrightarrow  \forall x (P \rightarrow  \phi(x))$

Prenex 6: $P \rightarrow \exists x \: \phi(x) \Leftrightarrow  \exists x (P \rightarrow  \phi(x))$

Prenex 7: $\forall x \: \phi(x) \rightarrow P \Leftrightarrow  \exists x (\phi(x) \rightarrow P)$

Prenex 8: $\exists x \: \phi(x) \rightarrow P \Leftrightarrow  \forall x (\phi(x) \rightarrow P)$

So take care of those last two: the quantifier changes if you pull it outside a conditional, and it is the antecedent of that conditional!

And because of the latter, there is no simple equivalence involving pulling a quantifier outside a biconditional.

OK, so for b)

You're good up to this point:

$$∀x ((∃y (dog(y) ∧ \neg admires(y, x)) \vee ∀y (\neg dog(y) \vee stronger(x, y)) )\space ∧ \space (∃y (dog(y) ∧ \neg stronger(x, y)) \vee ∀y (\neg dog(y) \vee admires(y, x))))$$

Now you want to pull your quantifiers out, but *first* you should rename the variables, otherwise quantifiers will 'capture' variables that they were not quantifying. So:

$$∀x ((∃y_1 (dog(y_1) ∧ \neg admires(y_1, x)) \vee ∀y_2 (\neg dog(y_2) \vee stronger(x, y_2)) )\space ∧ \space (∃y_3 (dog(_3) ∧ \neg stronger(x, y_3)) \vee ∀y_4 (\neg dog(y_4) \vee admires(y_4, x))))$$

OK, since you worked everything down to the boolean connectives $\land$, $\lor$, and $\not$, and you have worked any $\not$'s inside the quantifiers, we can pull the quantifiers out as they are. Again, I recoemmend pulling out the existentials first. So:

$$∀x ∃y_1 ∃y_3 ∀y_2 ∀y_4 (( (dog(y_1) ∧ \neg admires(y_1, x)) \vee  (\neg dog(y_2) \vee stronger(x, y_2)) )\space ∧ \space ( (dog(_3) ∧ \neg stronger(x, y_3)) \vee  (\neg dog(y_4) \vee admires(y_4, x))))$$

And yes, for you final step, distribute any $\lor$'s over $\land$'s:

$$∀x ∃y_1 ∃y_3 ∀y_2 ∀y_4 (( (dog(y_1) \lor (\neg dog(y_2) \vee stronger(x, y_2))) ∧ (\neg admires(y_1, x) \vee  (\neg dog(y_2) \vee stronger(x, y_2))) )\space ∧ \space ( (dog(_3) \vee (\neg dog(y_4) \vee admires(y_4, x))) ∧ (\neg stronger(x, y_3) \vee  (\neg dog(y_4) \vee admires(y_4, x))))$$

And we can drop some parentheses because of association:

$$∀x ∃y_1 ∃y_3 ∀y_2 ∀y_4 ( (dog(y_1) \lor \neg dog(y_2) \vee stronger(x, y_2) ∧ (\neg admires(y_1, x) \vee  \neg dog(y_2) \vee stronger(x, y_2) ) \space ∧ \space  (dog(_3) \vee \neg dog(y_4) \vee admires(y_4, x)) ∧ (\neg stronger(x, y_3) \vee  \neg dog(y_4) \vee admires(y_4, x))$$

Comment: ah I see it :), there should also be no negation symbol in front of the universal quantifier correct?

Comment: @PaulBotha Oh, right! I'll fix...

Comment: In a) I can't use the last two laws becuase `y` does exist as a free variable in admires(y,x) so what should I do? see my edit

Comment: @PaulBotha But the $y$ does not exists free in dog(x), so you can pull it over that one ... permission to edit your post to show this?

Comment: @PaulBotha Just did ... I used Prenex 3

Comment: @Brams28 is my edited a) correct now?

Comment: @PaulBotha. Yes, perfect!!  And for b), as I explain, there is unfortunately no way to directly pull out those quantifiers when you have a $\leftrightarrow$ .. The only thing to do is exactly what you do: rewrite as conditionals, and then as disjunctions ... So you get a *bunch* of quantifiers ... But using the Prenex laws you can pull them out one by one. One tip: bring out the existentials first ... It'll simplify Skolemization!

Comment: @PaulBotha Just noticed something about your algorithm. I added something about that to my answer.

Comment: not sure if I understood what you mean, sorry... see my edit :)

Comment: @PaulBotha Sorry, I have to go for a few hours ... Will look at it later.

Comment: @PaulBotha OK, I finally had some time look at your b) ... you didn't do that quite right. See my updated Answer.  I did edit your post just to add or remove some parentheses that weren't quite right

Answer (score 0):

For $(a)$ you can use truth tables. Compute the whole truth table of your formula:
\begin{array}
pp & q & r & s & (p\wedge\neg q)\vee(r\wedge \neg s) & CNF\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \underline0 & \_\_\_\_\_ \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \underline0 & \_\_\_\_\_ \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \underline1 & \_\_\_\_\_ \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & \underline0 & \_\_\_\_\_ \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \underline0 & \_\_\_\_\_ \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & \underline0 & \_\_\_\_\_ \\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & \underline1 & \_\_\_\_\_ \\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \underline0 & \_\_\_\_\_ \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \underline1 & \_\_\_\_\_ \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \underline1 & \_\_\_\_\_ \\
 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \underline1 & \_\_\_\_\_ \\
 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & \underline1 & \_\_\_\_\_ \\
 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \underline0 & \_\_\_\_\_ \\
 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & \underline0 & \_\_\_\_\_ \\
 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & \underline1 & \_\_\_\_\_ \\
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \underline0 & \_\_\_\_\_ \\
\end{array}
Now, knowing the values, you can construct your function in CNF.

For $(b)$, you made an error in the fourth step (from Def $\rightarrow$ to De Morgan) you changed the variable $y$ for an $x$. If you correct that i think you can, straightforward, get the universal quantifiers to the front and use the same principle to bring it to $CNF$.

Comment: Could you please expand on how to use the truth table to get to CNF or provide appropriate reading for me?